# Asymptotic Distribution of Z-Test Statistic Using Weak(*) Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space (i.e., a measure space with $\mu\leq 1$), and let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables on $\Omega$ with finite second moments. Without loss of generality, suppose that $$\int X_i\,\mathrm dP = 0\qquad\text{and}\qquad\int X_i^2\,\mathrm dP = 1.$$
Now define a new sequence $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of real-valued random variables by $$Z_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$
for each $n\in\mathbb N$. By the Central Limit Theorem, $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$  converges in distribution to a real-valued random variable whose distribution $Q$ is a standard normal distribution (the distribution $Q$ is the pushforward measure of $P$ under $Y$).

I want to obtain this result using a functional theoretic approach. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, denote the distribution of $Z_n$ by $\mu_n$. Then $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence in the real Banach space $\mathcal M(\mathbb R)$ of finite signed Borel measures on $\mathbb R$ equipped with the total variation norm. In this setting, convergence in distribution of $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to $Y$ translates to weak* convergence of $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to $Q$. To establish weak* convergence, we need to know the continuous dual space of $\mathcal M(\mathbb R)$. The continuous dual space of $\mathcal M(\mathbb R)$ can be identified by the space $\mathcal C(K)$ of real-valued continuous functions on $K$, where $K$ is some complicated compact space (the Stone–Čech of $\mathbb R$ to be precise). So, by definition of weak* convergence, $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $Q$ weak*ly iff $$\left\vert\int f\,\mathrm d\mu_n - \int f\,\mathrm dQ\right\vert$$ converges to $0$ for every $f$ in $\mathcal C(K)$.

So let $f$ be in $\mathcal C(K)$. Then it follows from the Law of Unconscious Statistician that $$\left\vert\int f\,\mathrm d\mu_n - \int f\,\mathrm dQ\right\vert = \left\vert\int f(Z_n)\,\mathrm dP - \int f(Y)\,\mathrm dP\right\vert.$$
For the ease of notation, I wrote $f(Z_n)$ instead of $f\circ Z_n$ and surpressed the region of integrations. I can plug in the definition of the $Z_n$s and use the Triangle Inequality to arrive at $$\int\left\vert f\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) - f(Y)\right\vert\,\mathrm dP.$$
But how do I proceed from there?

Comment: Proofs of the CLT using this method show that it suffices to consider $f$ that are nice, like $f(x) = x^k$. See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/